# JQuery drag/swip div in all directions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Here is where I am currently at with things:

```js
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(nTo) {
  nTo = nTo || 10;
  return Math.round(this * (1 / nTo)) * nTo;
};

$(function() {
  var slides = $('#slider ul').children().length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider').width();
  var min = 0;
  var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);
  console.log("Slides: " + slides + ", Width: " + slideWidth + ", min: 0, max: " + max);

  $("#slider ul").width(slides * slideWidth);
  $("#slider ul").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
      if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).animate({
        left: (ui.position.left).roundTo(slideWidth)
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#portfolio {
  background: #3aa756;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#portfolio-left {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#portfolio-right {
  background: #ded;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

#portfolio #slider {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider li {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" id="portfolio-left">
  &nbsp;
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" id="portfolio-right">
    <div id="slider">
      <ul>
        <li style="background-color: #F00"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Essentially, the right panel is draggable.  So if you drag to the left or right, a new colour panel will appear.  At the moment, I am using a `li` to hold the different panels

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li style="background-color: #F00"></li>
    <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
    <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I am after now is a little more complex.  Each `li` above should essentially act as a parent for more data.  So if I was to take the above, it might end up something more like this

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color: #F00">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: #CCC"></li>
                <li style="background-color: #5CB"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the left to right swipe will control the main `li` items.  I then want an up and down swipe to control the child items for a `li` parent.  So if I get to the first `li` that has some child data, an up swipe will display the first child li, another up swipe the second etc.  But then if I do a right swipe it will then display the second parent li.

Hope I explained it ok.  Is something like this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tweaked your code a little bit.

```js
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(nTo) {     
    nTo = nTo || 10;
    return Math.round(this * (1 / nTo)) * nTo;
};

$(function() {
  var slides = $('#slider ul').children('.par').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider').width();
  var min = 0;
  var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);
  console.log("Slides: " + slides + ", Width: " + slideWidth + ", min: 0, max: " + max);

  $("#slider ul").width(slides * slideWidth);
  $("#slider ul").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
      if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).animate({
        left: (ui.position.left).roundTo(slideWidth)
      });
    }
  });
  var slideHeight = $('#ch-data').height();
  var chelms = $('#ch-data').children().length;
  var inmax = -((chelms - 1) * slideHeight);
  var topin = slideHeight-50;
  $("#ch-data").height(chelms * slideHeight);
  $("#ch-data").width($('#ch-data li').width());
  $('#ch-data').css({'top': topin+'px'});
  $('#ch-data').draggable({
   axis: 'y',
   drag: function(event, ui){
     /*console.log('ui.position.top = '+ui.position.top);
    console.log('min = '+min);
    console.log('inmax = '+inmax);*/
   },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
     console.log('slideHeight = '+slideHeight);
     console.log('min = '+min);
     console.log('inmax = '+inmax);
     console.log('ui.position.top = '+ui.position.top);
     console.log('slideHeight-50 = '+topin);
     console.log('(ui.position.top).roundTo(topin) = '+(ui.position.top).roundTo(topin));
     if (ui.position.top > min) {
       if (ui.position.top > (slideHeight/2)) {
          ui.position.top = topin;
          $(this).animate({
            top: (ui.position.top).roundTo(topin)
          });
          console.log('if of > topin');
        }else{
     ui.position.top = min;
          $(this).animate({
            top: (ui.position.top).roundTo(slideHeight)
          });
          console.log('if of > min');
        }        
      }else if (ui.position.top < inmax) {
       ui.position.top = inmax;
       $(this).animate({
         top: (ui.position.top).roundTo(slideHeight)
       });
      console.log('if of > inmax');
      }else{
       $(this).animate({
         top: (ui.position.top).roundTo(slideHeight)
       });
      console.log('else');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    #portfolio {
  background: #3aa756;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#portfolio-left {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#portfolio-right {
  background: #ded;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

#portfolio #slider {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#ch-data{
  width: 380px;
  height: 100%;
}
#slider li.par {
  width: 390px;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

#slider li {
  width: 390px;
  height: 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" id="portfolio-left">
  &nbsp;
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" id="portfolio-right">
    <div id="slider">
      <ul>
        <li class="par" style="background-color: #F00">
          <ul id="ch-data">
            <li style="background-color: #CCC">inner1</li>
            <li style="background-color: #5CB">inner2</li>
            <li style="background-color: #58C">inner3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="par" style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
        <li class="par" style="background-color: #00F"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've reduced the width of inner `li`-s. So that you can see the red colour background of the parent. If we give full width for them, then the right to left drag won't work as we expected. I've followed your same code/method only. So that you can understand well. This is just for illustration. You might need to style accordingly to achieve better UI/UX results. Hope you got the idea.

I've updated the latest code.

- Now we can drag right to left and left to right
- Then we can drag sub panels up and down
- We can even move it down to hide the sub-panels to show the parent
  panel

Comment: @liam: JSFiddle would be fine to preview. That's why I put the link. http://jsfiddle.net/jerintk/x4k5qk1w/5/

Comment: Without the code you answer boils down to, look at this jsfiddle.

Comment: @liam: Agreed. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Looking at the fiddle, I can see the up and down drag works, but I cant seem to get the left to right working.

Comment: @kate_hudson: What I understood from your fiddle is, in the first instance/slide, there was no left to right drag. There was only right to left in the beginning. Then from the next slide onwards the left to right slide was there. Correct?

Comment: Oh I see what is happening.  The right to left/left to right should be available all the time.  So if you take my fiddle, you can always slide right to left.  So lets call the main panels P1, P2 and P3.  Each main panel will then have sub panels, controlled via up and down.  So say I slide to P2, I can then slide up to get to P2 -1, P2 - 2 etc.  If I then slide right again, I go to P3 etc

Comment: @kate_hudson: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/jerintk/x4k5qk1w/7/ I've updated the fiddle. See how's this working for you...

Comment: Very close :-) The only problem is that I can't get back from inner 1 to its parent panel (so I can pull inner 1 up, but then cant pull it back down to get the the red panel again).  Also, once you get to say inner2, you can drag it by actually dragging the panel.  To get to inner 1, is it possible to get to it by dragging up the red panel?

Comment: @kate_hudson: Sorry, I was late... I got your first point. I believe, this http://jsfiddle.net/jerintk/x4k5qk1w/10/ is what you need... But I'm not clear about the second point. You can drag from inner-2 to inner-1 and vice versa. Once you dragged the inner-1 up, there is no red panel, It'll be covered by the inner panels. So please try to explain the second point...